# While running `vainfo`, I am getting "Cannot load cuvidGetDecodeStatus". What should I do? [Hardware Video Acceleration Firefox]

Tags: nvidia, firefox, hardware-acceleration

I am following [this guide](https://electro-dan.co.uk/blog/26/nvidia-firefox-hardware-video-decoding-on-linux-mint-20-%2F-ubuntu-20.04-(focal)) on how to enable hardware video acceleration on Firefox. I am using NVIDIA as my graphics card. I feel like I have done all the steps already. At the last part, you are supposed to verify that everything is working using `vainfo` in the terminal. The expected output is something like:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.13.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'nvidia'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.13 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: VA-API NVDEC driver
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      <unknown profile>               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

But my output is:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'nvidia'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
Cannot load cuvidGetDecodeStatus
       150.494945961 [3893-3893] ../src/vabackend.c: 132                     init Failed to load NVDEC functions
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
       150.495030514 [3893-3893] ../src/vabackend.c:2165       __vaDriverInit_1_0 Initialising NVIDIA VA-API Driver: 10
       150.495040252 [3893-3893] ../src/vabackend.c:2174       __vaDriverInit_1_0 Now have 0 (0 max) instances
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
vaInitialize failed with error code 1 (operation failed),exit
```

EDIT:
When I run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` in the terminal this is what I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Okay, I have now added the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` to my question